# How do I find the click position on a square element?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

When I click on a square element I want to know the exact position of where it was clicked, how do I do that?

Comment: You can get the `click` event's `pageX` and `pageY` property

Answer (score 0):

pls read this
[MouseEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent)

you can use `e.clientX` and `e.clientY`